# data insertion into backend faild with angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to insert data into database using angular but I found that the response of post request gives me null and the data doesn't insert on database, I used SoapUI to check my backend

[image: service parametres:]

and It works.

for more information, this is a worked code of AJax:

```
var _addOrUpdateDriverElement = function () {
            // DriverElement AddOrUpdateDriverElement(String SessionId, int DriverElementId, String FirstName, String LastName, String DriverCode,
            //String Email, String Tel, int DepartmentId)
            Tunav.openJqxWindowLoading(true);
            var jData = {};
            jData.SessionId = "";
            var idDriverElement = -1;
            if (_driverElement != null) {
                idDriverElement = _driverElement.key;
            }
            jData.DriverElementId = idDriverElement;
            jData.FirstName = $("#" + _controls.jqxInput.FirstName.id).val();
            jData.LastName = $("#" + _controls.jqxInput.LastName.id).val();
            jData.DriverCode = "";// $("#" + _controls.jqxInput.DriverCode.id).val();
            jData.Email = $("#" + _controls.jqxInput.Email.id).val();
            jData.Tel = $("#" + _controls.jqxInput.Tel.id).val();
            jData.DepartmentId = $("#" + controls.jqxComboBox.Departments.id).jqxComboBox("getSelectedItem") == null ? -1 : $("#" + controls.jqxComboBox.Departments.id).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '****',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(jData),
                success: function (response, type, xhr) {
                    Tunav.openJqxWindowLoading(false);
                    var dep = response.AddOrUpdateDriverElementResult;
                    if (dep != null) {
                        _closeWindow();
                        _publishAddOrUpdateDriverElementEvent(dep);
                        Tunav.UIDriverManagement.openJqxWindowInfo(Tunav.UIDriverManagement.Controls.JqxWindowInfo.messageToShow.successfulRegistration, false);
                    } else {
                        Tunav.UIDriverManagement.openJqxWindowInfo(messageToShow.errorRegistration, false);
                    }
    }, 
                error: function (xhr) {
                    Tunav.openJqxWindowLoading(false);
                    Tunav.callFromServerError(xhr);
                }
```

Now I have tried  that code on my service:

```
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }
  private GeneralURL = '****';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 AddDriverElement(name,lastname,code,email,tel,depId){
    let dataupdate = {
      SessionId: localStorage.getItem('sessionId'),
      DriverElementId: -1,
      FirstName: name,
      LastName: lastname,
      DriverCode: code,
      Email: email,
      Tel: tel,
      DepartementId: depId
     }
     //debugger;
    return this.http.post(`${this.GeneralURL}/AddOrUpdateDriverElement`, JSON.stringify(dataupdate), this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: If you use angular - you not need to use jquery ajax ($.ajax)

Comment: Yeah I use the second code not the first but I have tried the first on normal HTML project and it work

Comment: i think you not need JSON.stringify()

Comment: I tried it to but not work

Comment: I used JSON.stringify(dataupdate)*

Comment: do you know how to see the response at 'network panel' of chrome?

Comment: Yeah and the respance: {"AddOrUpdateDriverElementResult":null}

Comment: it is looks like you reach the server but fail to pass data in correct format. try to compare the "payload" section in devtools - what are difference between request with jquery and with angular

Comment: also it will be good to attach screenshot of payload

Comment: maybe 'dataType: 'json',' ?